# How Can I use operator forkJoin of an Observable in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I need to do the following:

Get the users administrators and professionals of the same collection in this case street "users", I am working with the latest version of AngularFire, this works this Observables.

How can I make two requests in parallel and the answer be the union of the administrator and professional users.

I tried using the forkJoin operator like this:

```
 getUsers(): Observable<any> {
  return forkJoin([
    this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('roles.admin', '==', true)).valueChanges(),
    this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('roles.professional', '==', true)).valueChanges()
  ])
  .map((data: any) => {
    console.log(data)
    return data;
  });
```

}

But doesn't executes, I call the method so:

```
   this.userSrv.getUsers()
    .subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
```

These are my imports:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Is there other way to do this.
I'd appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that `.valueChanges()` returns a [‘hot’ observable](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339), which will never `complete`. And from the [forkjoin docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin):

> Wait for Observables to complete and then combine last values they
>   emitted.

So what you’re looking for is probably [`.combineLatest()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest):

```
getUsers(): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.combineLatest(
    this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('roles.admin', '==', true)).valueChanges(),
    this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('roles.professional', '==', true)).valueChanges()
  )
  .map((data: any) => {
    console.log(data)
    return data;
  });
}
```

That should log an array of two items representing the two collections whenever either of the collections are updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like :

```
let url1 = this.http.get('https://url1');
let url2 = this.http.get('http://url2');

forkJoin([url1, url2]).subscribe(results => {
  // results[0] is url1 response
  // results[1] is url2 response
  this.url1reponse = results[1];
  this.url2reponse = results[0];
});
```

Comment: could you maybe share a plunker ?